# adding jQuery UI bounce effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jquery ui to have images bounce in and out of a div. I have all the images loaded in a hidden div. I have a recursive jquery function that displays the images in a separate div in an infinite loop. I would like to add the effect of the image bouncing in and then out.

Currently I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var imgarray = jQuery('img','#hide');

(function recurse(counter) {
    var imgobj = imgarray[counter];
    jQuery('.slides_container img').remove();
    jQuery('.slides_container').delay('1200').prepend(
        '<img id="theImg" src="' + imgarray[counter].src + '" />'
    );
    delete imgarray[counter];
    imgarray.push(imgobj);
    setTimeout(function() {
        recurse(counter + 1);
    }, 2000);
})(0);

});
```

and

```
<div id="hide">
     <img src="example1.png" />
     <img src="example2.png" />
</div>

<div class="slides_container"></div>
```

How can I add the bounce in effect?

Comment: you will have to use a `.animate()` function.  I would also suggest looking into the `jQuery easing` plugin.  It has a "Bounce" effect http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: @Dom Wow. Seriously? I have jQueryUI. I'm not asking about that. I'm asking how to implement the effect into the code I already have.

Comment: @Jordy If you can try to put what you have into a working jsfiddle, it can help me more to help you out.  I kind of see where the animate would work, but I need to see what it's doing right now.  Otherwise, I would just rewrite it for you, but that's not efficient for either of us.  Comment back again if you create one!

Comment: @ntgCleaner I got the animate in and out working. I can't figure out now how to get it to delay in between animations. I have tried chaining them together. When I add the delay it seems to not run the second animation. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/32cxA/

Comment: @Jordy You will have to use `setTimeout()` to make the delay.  `.delay()` only works on animations (and I think a few other small things) on that element alone.  If something changes that can not be animated, you will have to make a timeout.  What is the desired outcome?  You would like the image to go back up?

Comment: Here's the updated jsfiddle, sorry I gave you the first save: http://jsfiddle.net/32cxA/17/ .... I just want a delay between the two animations. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close your use of the delay is not doing anything because jquery is executing you next block of code and removing that image before it can transition out. You have a couple of options to fix this.

Wrap your ease out animation with the rest in a time out like:
http://jsfiddle.net/32cxA/22/

```
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.slides_container img').animate({
        top: '-=700'
    }, 1500, 'easeInBounce');
    delete imgarray[counter];
    imgarray.push(imgobj);
    setTimeout(function() {
        recurse(counter + 1);
    }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Or keep your .delay() and just wrap the rest of the code in a setTimeout equal to the total transition time like:
http://jsfiddle.net/32cxA/25/

```
jQuery('.slides_container img').animate({
        top: '+=700'
    }, 1200, 'easeOutBounce').delay(2000).animate({
            top: '-=700'
        }, 1500, 'easeInBounce');
    setTimeout(function() {
        delete imgarray[counter];
        imgarray.push(imgobj);
        setTimeout(function() {
            recurse(counter + 1);
        }, 2000);
    }, 4700);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the code a bit, and it might not be what you're looking for, but instead of using an array to number whichever you want, I've used the modulus sign (`%`) to get which number the element is and then I use an increasing integer (You can also use a for loop if you need more control).

Here's the code I have and you can use this however you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var numBalls = $('#hidden img').length; //Find out how many images are in queue.
    i = 0; //Start a counter
    setInterval(function(){ //Every (3000) ms run this action
        i++; //Up the counter by 1
        $('img:nth-of-type(' + (i%numBalls + 1) + ')').animate({top: '+=700'}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce').delay(1000).animate({top: '-=700'}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce') //animate the image.  The correct image is selected by (i%numBalls+1)
    },3000);
});
```

If you have to use an array count, I can work around this, but here is the fiddle to show what I believe you're looking for.  Take a look at the comments here as well to explain what is happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/wxBck/

Also, by using your code, I edited your fiddle to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/32cxA/27/

I added a delay in between the two animations, you may not have seen this working if you tried this because your setTimeout delay was shorter than the entirety of the animation